# JS Date subtraction returning NaN

Tags: javascript, date, nan

I have two variables storing dates, and I'm trying to subtract them.

I've printed out the values and the subtraction, but I can't figure out what's breaking here.

Code

```
var dateRan = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});   
  console.log(
  "date1 is "+ new Date(firstDate*1000).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
  + " and date2 is "+ dateRan
  + " and date1 - date2 is "+ Math.abs((new Date(firstDate*1000)-dateRan)));
```

From the log:

```
 date1 is  7/5/2020, 10:44:37 PM and date2 is 7/5/2020, 10:22:30 PM and date1 - date2 is NaN
```

I could have sworn this was working fine a couple weeks ago - I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: Can you share your date variable declaration and code that populates them?

Comment: typeof dateRan?

Comment: `toLocaleString()` returns a string just like it's name implies. Date - Date String = NaN

Comment: firstDate and dateRan are dates?

Comment: Oh, I think I cut out the numeric Date() variable! Thanks @charlietfl

Comment: Yeah...you got it. Could just subtract another new Date() also. Gets cast to now() automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dateRan is a String; specifically, the new Date() converted to a String by toLocaleString().

An Object minus a String yields Nan.

An Object plus a String yields a string. This can give strange results.

```
var dateOne = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"});
var dateTwo = new Date();
console.log(dateOne - dateTwo); // NaN
console.log(dateOne + dateTwo); // 7/5/2020, 10:47:01 PMSun Jul 05 2020 22:47:12 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(new Date() - new Date());  // 0
console.log(new Date() + new Date());  // Sun Jul 05 2020 22:52:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)Sun Jul 05 2020 22:52:51 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: "*An Object minus a String yields Nan*" not necessarily. The minus operator coerces the values to Number, so the Date is converted to it's time value (which might be NaN but not if created by `new Date()`), the string returns NaN because `Number('7/5/2020, 10:44:37 PM')` returns NaN and any value minus NaN evaluates to NaN. An expression like `new Date() - '5'` returns a number (the time value minus 5 ms).

Comment: You are correct. {} - "4" yields -4. {} - "a" yields NaN. {} + "4" yields 4 but console.log({} + "4") prints "[object Object]4". It is difficult to write a few sentences about JavaScript type conversions without getting something wrong.